# Visual Basic exception with settings

Tags: vb.net

I've busy with Visual Basic for over 2/3 weeks now, so i'm still quit a noob with this :s

I've got my  project, and every time  you click a button that has anything to do with the setting 'username' the project gives this exception:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: can't initialise the configuration system  (translated from dutch)

It just came out of the nothing! I searched here and there, but none of  the solutions worked so far (Or i don't knwo how to do  them)

Sorry if this is already asked! :c But anyone who has an idea to fix  this? Tanks!

If it's handy, the error  refers to this  block of code:

```
 <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(), _
 Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
 Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")> _
Public Property Gebruuikersnaam() As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("Gebruuikersnaam"), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me("Gebruuikersnaam") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: can you link to the solutions you tried so we know what not to suggest? You can edit your question to do this

Comment: Please check your app.config with some XML Online Parser. Probably is a malformed XML file

Comment: And uuhm..what is a XML Online Parser? (sorry!)

Comment: An online XML parser is anything that can validate an XML file for you and is [located on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=validate+XML+online). Validate your app.config with that.

Comment: I checked  it  with http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and there we're no errors :s

Comment: What happens if you go to the Settings in the project properties? Do you have `<userSettings>` node in app.config?

Comment: In settings I can see all my variables (Password, username etc)  There is an  <userSettings>  line

Comment: It is a typical "newbie" mishap, it happens when you don't give projects a good name and just accept the Visual Studio default.  Which makes it likely to load a user.config file that once belonged to an old deleted project.  Which has the wrong content.  Nothing actually goes wrong, the exception notification disappears once you write the code to give the setting a value.  So a new user.config file is written, overwriting the old one.  Just keep motoring.

Comment: But the setting is standard empty and you have to give it a value in the program. And if you try that, it crashes :s Shoudl i give it a standard value like 'x'?

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work :(

Comment: Try creating new solution and pasting code there.

Comment: I rebuild the solution, but (i know this  is a  dumb question, sorry again!) wich code? :s Btw, thanks for helping and answering so  quick!

Comment: All the code. Just transfer to the new solution. Possibly with "Add existing item".

Comment: Okay, uhm i've got the  solution.. I just upload  it to  Mediafire?  (*name*.snl'?) http://www.mediafire.com/download/v1af9ac15ac9hgz/ThatsABurby3.sln Hope this is right!

Comment: I suggested you create a new solution and move your code from your old solution to the new solution. I did not ask you to upload any files.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding! I'm doing it now, thanks for your help! Can I avoid this in th future by making backups?